# JavaScript array into formData

Tags: javascript, arrays, ajax

Am having trouble passing an array via Ajax to PHP.

please see jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/CraigDavison/9spyn7ah/

```
 function autoPopulate() {
   var cast = "John Wayne, Julia Roberts, Kevin Spacey";
   cast = cast.split(', ');
   var arr_cast = [];

   $.each(cast, function() {
      arr_cast.push(this);
   });
   return_ajax_result('app/handlers/get_cast_ids.php', {cast: arr_cast});
}
```

I have created an array from a string. the string is a list of actors from a movie. I want to pass that list of actors through as an array assoiated with "Cast" so cast=[actor 1, actor 2, actor 3].

It all seems to go wrong when I try to append this to the formData as this remains empty.

Any thoughts please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the `.each` function to make another array, by splitting your string, you've already made an array for variable `cast`. Your ajax method looks correct but it can be done with request body, you don't necessarily need FormData in this case. FormData is mostly used for file uploads.

For the error handler it is recommended to use something like `err` or `error` for the callback value, it provides more readability for yourself and other.

I forked your fiddle and made some changes to the code:

```
function autoPopulate() {
  var cast = "John Wayne, Julia Roberts, Kevin Spacey";
  cast = cast.split(', ');
  return_ajax_result('app/handlers/get_cast_ids.php', {cast});
}

function return_ajax_result(url, params) {
  var request = $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: params,
    beforeSend: function() {
      $(".ng-loading-container").addClass("ng-loading-container-show");
    },
    success: function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    },
    error: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    },
  });
};

autoPopulate()
```

The fiddle can be found here: [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mxdi9i7/ra2wsnyx/)

Comment: Thanks, I should have come back on sooner but I worked it out in the end. Been on a JS sabbatical and was a little rusty.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need any formData at all.

Just put to yout `data` the `params`

```
  var request = $.ajax({
    method: 'post',
    url: url,
    data: params,
    ...
  });
```

Jquery will automaticaly do all necesary stuff.